# Is there any automated process to download POI from Wikimapia?

Tags: point-of-interest, wikimapia

Is there any automated process to download point of intrest from Wikimapia. I want to download some features such as Schools

Comment: plz use overpass-api it was made for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Motomapia.

http://www.motomapia.com/

You have to pan/zoom inside a fixed area to finalise the POI window and then click download.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the wikimapia API http://wikimapia.org/api/

Specifically, you can use the API box to get the data from the category such as 'Schools' as KML http://wikimapia.org/wiki/API_box

Comment: Thank u, it is an usefull information, without using api is any other tool available.